# Cakephp 3 best coding practice for model functions

Tags: php, oop, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.1

I have a current_day_users table and users table.What is the better coding practice between the following to extract data from current_day_users:

1.UsersTable.php code

```
   $this->CurrentDayUsers->find()->where(['user_id'=>$userId,'created'=>$dateToday])->first();
```

2. UsersTable.php code

   $this->CurrentDayUsers->findUser($userId,$dateToday);

CurrentDayusersTable.php code

```
public function findUser($userId,$date){
    return  $this->find()->where(['user_id'=>$userId,'created'=>$date])->first();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have CurrentDayUsers  table, I'd suggest you to follow the second approach:

```
public function findUser($userId,$date){
   return  $this->find()->where(['user_id'=>$userId,'created'=>$date])->first();
}
```

This is provides  a clean and compact code instead of using the query builder within Users Table.